# Google Fonts not getting imported with styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to use a google font in a styled component, but it's not able to import the font while running.
This is my code. I'm unable to find the issue here..

```js
const StyledProductTitle = styled.h1`
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap");

  font-family: "Press Start 2P", cursive;
  font-size: 6em;
  color: rgb(255, 206, 70);

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
`;

function Header() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledProductTitle>XYZ</StyledProductTitle>
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT 1:

Found a workaround for this.

I removed the import statements in the styled components and created a separate css file with just import statements to import the fonts from google. Importing this css in the react component seems to work.